# How to run splashAnimation in UIThread without lagging during AsyncTask call?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I have application, which needs to load data in specific order. The reason for that is simple. `Data1` are needed to construct `Data2` etc. For example if you have application which is loading **user profile**, you need user profile data to load other stuff in app.

So I call `api.startup()` AsyncTask, which will inside `onPreExecute()` call `animation onUIThread` and inside `doInBackground()` method it will call another api `asyncTask` call(called `getData1()`).

As that one call ends and data are received in `CallBack`, and if it's success, it will callanother asyncTask().

Below you can see how it should work. But what will happen is that as `getData1()` asyncTask is ended, it will switch to `onPostExecute()`(inside `api.startup()`) and return true to my callback. But `data2 3 4 5` are still running and this makes my splashAnimation laggy.

How to solve this issue?

[image]

```
api.splashStartup(this)



fun startupRequest(): Boolean {

        var INSTALLATION_ID: String? = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.SharedPrefs),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?.getString(getString(R.string.INSTALLATION_ID), null)

        if(INSTALLATION_ID == null){
            createInstallationID()
            INSTALLATION_ID = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.SharedPrefs),
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?.getString(getString(R.string.INSTALLATION_ID), null)
        } 

        api.postStartup(INSTALLATION_ID!!, object: IStartupCallback {

            override fun onError(errorJSON: JSONObject) {
                createLog("SplashScreen", "Startup API Error -> " + errorJSON.toString())
                createToast(errorJSON.toString())

            }

            override fun onSuccess(startupJSON: JSONObject?) {
                createLog("SplashScreen", "Startup API Success -> " + startupJSON.toString())

                val X_SESSION: String? = startupJSON?.getString("session")
                val userID: Int = startupJSON.getInt("user_id")
                loadData1(X_SESSION, userID)

            }
    }
    return true
}

private fun loadData1(X_SESSION: String, userID: Int){

        api.getData1(X_SESSION, userID,  object: IData1Callback{
            override fun onError(errorJSON: JSONObject) {
                createLog("SplashScreenLoadData1", "Data1 API Error -> " + errorJSON.toString())
            }

            override fun onSuccess(data1: JSONObject?) {
                //do some stuff with data
                addDataToSingleton(data1)
                loadData2(data1.getString("object_Hash"))
            }
        })
    }

private fun loadData2(objectHash: String){

        api.getData2(objectHash,  object: IData2Callback{
            override fun onError(errorJSON: JSONObject) {
                createLog("SplashScreenLoadData2", "Data2 API Error -> " + errorJSON.toString())
            }

            override fun onSuccess(data1: JSONObject?) {
                //do some stuff with data
                addDataToSingleton(data2)
                loadData3(data2)
            }
        })
    }

////

API CLASS


fun splashStartup(splashActivity: Splash){
        class GetSplashAsync: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

            override fun onPreExecute() {
                createLog("SplashScreen: ", "Starting onPreExecute() --> anim on UIThread")
                splashActivity.splashAnimation()
            }

            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {

                return splashActivity.startupRequest()
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
                createLog("StartupAsync ", "startup async ended")
            }

        }

        GetSplashAsync().execute()
}



fun postStartup(INSTALLATION_ID: String, callback: IStartupCallback){

        class PostStartupAsync(private val startupCallback: IStartupCallback): AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): JSONObject {

                val server = Server.getInstance(context!!)
                val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                jsonObject.put("installation", installation)

                return server.doPost(context.getString(R.string.startup_resource_link), jsonObject)
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: JSONObject?) {
                super.onPostExecute(result)
                if(result!!.has("ErrorCode") && result.getInt("ErrorCode") == errServerOffline
                        || result.has("ErrorCode") && result.getInt("ErrorCode") == errServerNotResponding){
                    startupCallback.onError(result)
                } else if (result.has("error")){
                    startupCallback.onError(result)
                } else {
                    startupCallback.onSuccess(result)
                }
            }
        }

        PostStartupAsync(callback).execute()
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some code? Abstract descriptions are good for when you're designing the process, but are terrible for debugging.

Comment: There is a glipse of code. I will not post all asyncTasks. Just to see how it works

Comment: That doesn't really help me, but try this: instead of posting the next AsyncTask from `onPostExecute()`, which is run in the main Thread, post it at the end of `doInBackground()`. You can still do the animation in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that's not how the execution works.

A thread execute statement one by one. So when you reach a statement where a new thread is started then the previous thread will not wait for this thread to finish things, instead it will move to next statement.

Similarly, when you execute your startup AsyncTask and in `doInBackground()` you call a method `startupRequest()`. Now this method is starting a new AsyncTask (new thread), so this method will return true just after starting the Async task. And you get its response in onPostExecute(). Now the `startup AsyncTask` is already done and the next AsyncTask is working.

What you can do is -

1) Start the animation in first api call and end it in the last API call,OR

2) Call all the API request in same AsyncTask.

```
public MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>() {

    public void onPreExecute() {
       //start animation
    }

    public Boolean doInBackground(Void ignore) {

       JSONObject res1 = loadData1();   // Sync call to API
       if (res1 is Success) {
          JSONObject res2 = loadData2();   // Sync call to API
          if (res2 is Success) {
              JSONObject res3 = loadData3();   // Sync call to API
              if (res1 is Success) {
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }
      return false;
   }

   public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
       // stop animation
       if (result) {
          // show home
       } else {
         // show error
       }
   }
}
```

loadData() calls are Sync API call, means you dont need to run AsyncTask in then. Just call the API directly.